# send message to more than one IP address with socat

Tags: bash, socat

I want to write a bash script in linux to get several IP addresses and use `socat` to listen on port 5000 and if received a message send it to all of IP addresses.

How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop for this.  Suppose you have a list of IP addresses in a file named ipaddresses.txt

```
for ips in `cat ipaddresses.txt` ; do
  dowhatever
done
```

Alternatively you could do something like this.

```
for ips in `ifconfig | grep 'inet addr' | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'` ; do
  dowhatever
done
```